# How to convert a PCRE regex pattern with match reset for ECMAScript?

Tags: javascript, string, split

Suppose I have the following pattern:

```
|              |                 |      |      |         |
|            |           |      |      |         |
|              |     |      |      |         |
```

I am interested in a `regex` expression that can match anything between the second and third `|` characters, as shown below.

[image]

I can do this using the following pattern `^\|\s+\|\K\s+(?=\|)` ([`regex` demo here](https://regex101.com/r/wumSrI/1)) with the `PCRE` flavor.

However, my requirement is to find a pattern supported by the `ECMAScript` flavor. The use of the match reset (i.e., `\K`) does not work in this case. Do you have any ideas on how to obtain something similar that works in `ECMAScript`?

Comment: Does it have to be a regular expression? This seems like something that is much easier solved by just iterating over the string (or use `indexOf`).

Comment: @FelixKling, Not necessarily. I assumed a regular expression would be easier, but I am open to any suggestions!

Comment: Just split with `|`, why use regex? Is it done in JavaScript?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Okay, you guys are right, I'm overthinking this. I'm going with the split option.

Comment: Just capture and discard. From `^\|[^|]+\|([^|]+)` you just need capture group #1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While splitting is indeed easier, I still wanted to see if I could do it with regex.  You can use lookahead to match the pattern from the beginning of the line, and within the lookahead, capture the contents of what you're looking for in a capture group.

Example: https://regex101.com/r/v0GnAN/1

`(?=^\|[^|]*\|([^|]*?)\|)`

This is a lookahead group that's looking for anything between two `|` characters, then matching the same but within a capture group.  This is slightly different from the `\K` approach in that your results are now in group 1 instead of group 0.

Comment: It works nicely, @Richard and it's an interesting use of the lookahead I am glad you shared. I am accepting your solution as the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As indicated in the comments this can be much easier solver by splitting the string on `|`.

```js
// The string with 'a', 'b', and 'c' added for clarity.
const string = "|              |        a         |      |      |         |\n|            |     b      |      |      |         |\n|              |   c  |      |      |         |";

// Print the string.
console.log(string);

// Split and print the regions between the 2nd and 3rd `|`.
string.split('\n').forEach(line => {
    console.log(line.split('|', 3)[2])
});
```