# How can I test if an expression is valid for TextMate grammars in VS Code?

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, oniguruma

I am trying to use VS Code's tokenization engine for grammar injections and I don't understand why some regular expressions fail.

For example, suppose I have the following text.

```
VS Code, TextMate grammars, and Oniguruma regular expressions.
```

Then, I want to match `Oniguruma` using the following `regex` (i.e., [see demo](https://regex101.com/r/7svfsq/2)):

```regex
(?=and\s+(Oniguruma)\s+regular)
```

Based on the demo above, the regular expression seems to match (capture?) what I want (i.e., see below).

[image: demo matching]

However, when trying this in the context of VS Code grammars, it fails. More specifically, the `./syntaxes/some.test.injection.json` file contains:

```json
{
    "scopeName": "some.test.injection",
    "injectionSelector": "L:text.html.markdown",
    "patterns": [
        { "include": "#test" }
    ],
    "repository": {
        "test": {
            "match": "(?=and\\s+(Oniguruma)\\s+regular)",
            "captures": {
                "1": { "name" : "some.test" }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then, in `package.json` I have:

```json
{
    // ...
    "contributes": {
        "grammars": [
            {
                "scopeName": "some.test.injection",
                "path": "./syntaxes/some.test.injection.json",
                "injectTo": ["text.html.markdown"]
            }
        ]
    },
    // ...
}
```

Finally, the token color rule in `settings.json` looks like this:

```json
{
    "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
        "textMateRules": [
            { "scope": "some.test", "settings": { "foreground": "#dfd43b" } },
        ]
    }
}
```

As you can see below, the token is not parsed:

[image]

However, the token gets parsed when I use the following `regex` (i.e., [see demo](https://regex101.com/r/7svfsq/3)) instead:

```regex
(?<=and\s)(Oniguruma)(?=\s+regular)
```

As seen during the inspection of the editor token and scopes:

[image]

From the [VS Code documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/syntax-highlight-guide#textmate-grammars) (i.e., see below) I understand that I need to use `Oniguruma` regular expressions:

> TextMate grammars rely on Oniguruma regular expressions and are typically written as a plist or JSON. You can find a good introduction to TextMate grammars here, and you can take a look at existing TextMate grammars to learn more about how they work.

My question is twofold:

1. Why does the first expression fail? Is it not a valid `Oniguruma` regular expression?
2. How can I test whether a regular expression is a valid `Oniguruma` regular expression?

Comment: you ONLY have a Positive Lookadhead Assertion, this is a zero-length position, so nothing is matched, match length is 0, read more about Regex

Comment: Thank you for your very insightful comment. Then how do you explain that the capturing works [here](https://regex101.com/r/7svfsq/2)?

Comment: if you use `captures` you can use `and\s(Oniguruma)\s+regular` no need to use lookahead or look behind

Comment: My question is not about needing a `regex` expression. I am interested to know why the capture I can get in the first place is not working in VS Code and to what extent it is or is not a valid `Oniguruma` expression.

Comment: I would say it is a bug in regex101, you don't have capture groups in lookahead/behind, because it is not part of the matched text, If you write it according to the rules of the `Oniguruma` docs it is an `Oniguruma` regex

Comment: Of course it is not a bug  at regex101. It is a peculiarity of the editor feature you are using for highlighting.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, if I understand you correctly, it's either (1) capturing inside a positive lookahead is not a valid expression for the `Oniguruma` engine, or (2) VS Code's (i.e., via TextMate grammars) version of the `Oniguruma` engine does not support this syntax, hence the peculiarity. I believe (2) is more likely, and I also found a [mention on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oniguruma) about an updated version, i.e., `Onigmo`, that introduces more features.

Comment: @rioV8, [here is another counterexample](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71650015/5252007) that using capture groups in lookaheads is acceptable. I too don't agree that there is a bug in `regex101`. Instead, I think VS Code uses an older version of the engine that does not support this syntax.

Comment: It is not the problem of the regex library but the peculiarity of the software that uses the regex library. Capturing inside positive lookaheads works fine in any regex flavor that supports lookarounds.

Comment: I see, and sadly this makes it harder to build an expression on `regex101` because I do not know how it will behave in VS Code. For example, even this one fails `\|\s+(\d[m])\s+\|` to capture `0m`, whereas, for whatever strange reason, this one succeeds `(?<=\|)(?:\s+)(\d[m])(?=\s+\|)`. Thank you for shedding some light on this issue.

Answer (score 2):

VSCode uses TextMate as the tokenization engine, and TextMate uses the oniguruma engine for Regex.

[Ruby 1.9+ uses the oniguruma engine](https://patshaughnessy.net/2012/4/3/exploring-rubys-regular-expression-algorithm#:%7E:text=Since%20version%201.9,as%20Japanese%20text.). And [Rubular](https://rubular.com/) uses ruby 2.5.9

I've been using Rubular to validate my VSCode TM grammars for a while and has never it failed once.

Answer (score -2):

I'm pretty sure your regex is being overridden by another one that is also present in the .tmLanguage.json file.
In order to check this, do the following:
in the file where you write regex (it is assumed that other patterns are also located in it) find(Ctrl + F) the following textmate scope: "text.html.markdown" (as shown in you in the screenshot), then with your regex completely replace the one that is registered for this scope and change the name to "some.test", then reload VSCode.